# Javascript regex for tag in comments

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been working on a web app in which users can comment and reply to comments, this uses a tagging system. The users are being tagged by their name which can contain more words so I've decided to mark the takes like this:

> &&John Doe&&

So a comment might look like this:

> &&John Doe&&, are you sure that &&Alice Johnson&& is gone?

I'm trying to write a regex to match use in a string.replace() javascript function, so the regex must match every single tag in the string.

So far I have:

```
^&&.+{2, 64}&&$
```

This isn't working so I'm sure something is wrong, in case you didn't understand what I meant, the regex from above is supposed to match strings like this:

> &&anythingbetween2and64charslong&&.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there some edge cases you want to consider? Like `&` inside a name or escaping mechnisms? Otherwise just go by `&&.{2,64}?&&`

Comment: No, the usernames will contain only alphabetic characters, whitespaces and  apostrophes.

Comment: Apparently, this works just fine, many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(.*?)&&` means "everything until &&" :

```js
var before = document.getElementById("before");
var after = document.getElementById("after");
var re = /&&(.*?)&&/g, b = "<b>$1</b>";

after.innerHTML = before.textContent.replace(re, b);
```

```html
<p id="before">&&John Doe&&, are you sure that &&Alice Johnson&& is gone?</p>
<p id="after"></p>
```

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` as it'll destroy events and triggers regeneration of the DOM. Instead, use something like [mark.js](https://markjs.io/), e.g. `new Mark(document.getElementById("before")).markRegExp(/&&(.*?)&&/g);`

Comment: You are right @dude, I use it for demo purpose only, but it can be misleading indeed :-)

Answer (score 0):

try `&{2}.{2,64}&{2}`

if you want to get the match in between add parentheses for the match group

`&{2}(.{2,64})&{2}`

right now your are only checking strings where the entire line matches

the `^` character means beginning of line
the `$` character means end of line
`\A` means beginning of entire string
`\Z` means end of entire string

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

```
str.match(/&&.{2,64}?&&/g)
```

- you need to remove `^` and `$` from the start and the end since they match the start and the end of the string.
- add a `/g` flag at the end so all the matches will be matched
- `?` after the `{}` makes the match non-greedy, so it will match the shortest possible string between "&&" instead of the longest (will give you "&&John Doe&&" instead of "&&John Doe&&, are you sure that &&Alice Johnson&&")

Read up on greediness: [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score -1):

This regex will match any Unicode letter between && signs:

```
str.match(/\&\&[\p{L}\p{N}]+(?:\s+[\p{L}\p{N}]+)*\&\&/g);
```

Here,

`\p{L}` --> Any unicode letter, the names can be any language and letter
`\p{N}` --> Any unicode digit
`[\p{L}\p{N}]+` --> A word constructed with unicode letters or digits
`\s+` --> Gaps between words, max 3 length
`[\p{L}\p{N}]+(?:\s+[\p{L}\p{N}]+)*` --> All word groups

Comment: Now this looks like a complete approach, thank you, sir!

Comment: Yeah, you know names are all from different kinds of languages so you have to use the unicode match-case for the regex pattern, updated it

Comment: This will only work with [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/). Native JS regex engine does not support Unicode property classes.

Comment: So @NelutuFona you gotta find a server-side approach, because I am sure you will face with this problem somehow

Comment: Yea, right now I need to buld a server-side approach for this(strictly for one name, used in URL), so basically I need a regex that will work with php 7 and will match any name, no shorter than 2 characters and no longer than 64

Comment: So yes, [\p{L}\p{N}]+(?:\s+[\p{L}\p{N}]+)* did the job. :)

Comment: Then retag the question. Also, the regex does not take into account diacritics. Not sure you need that.

Comment: Thank you @Nelutu, thinking wider always saves :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the question is not needed to be retagged, you have to think unicoded characters if you are dealing with names ;)

Comment: @webmaster: I do not really care since I relieved my downvote, but anyone coming here will be looking for a JavaScript regex, not a PHP regex. See, someone still kept a downvote on the answer.

Comment: You got me wrong, my problem is not the down-vote, just trying to break the bigoted thoughts

Comment: anyone coming here will be looking for a JavaScript regex --> How can you be sure 100%? You are not suitable for the IT world completely

Comment: tag in comments --> We all are using facebook and know what's happening when you write your friend's name becomes a bold text or something, so again, if you are dealing with names, you got to obey unicode